# List of components (wire twice)

Tags: hyperhtml

If I'm rendering a list of functions returning hyperhtml, I wind up wiring twice since omitting it somewhere won't work, and bind would only make sense on the parent, and then there's weak referencing to consider so it is awkward either way.

example

```
function list(){
  [{t: "t", c: "c"}].map((x,i)=>{
    return wire()'${item(x, i)}'
  }
}

function item(x, i){
  return wire(x)'${x.t}

bind(document)'${list()}'
```

Here recur will wire recur, which will then return yet again wired result. Hence if wind up using wire twice.

Comment: I have honestly no idea, without a code example, what you are talking about. All I can say is that wiring twice means you are doing something wrong, because none of the live example ever wired twice anything, unless strictly meant. Do you mind writing down a basic example so I can better help explaining what is wrong and/or why? Thank you.

Comment: updated with code

Comment: a function as content does not make sense ... it would be nice if you could go through the documentation and have a better idea of what wire is about and how you avoid duplicates: https://viperhtml.js.org/hyperhtml/documentation/#essentials-3

Comment: updated to list>item analogy, although a recursive function is valid for showing object/tree.

Comment: I think you are not reading the documentation ... I still don't understand your use case, sorry. Your code also does not use backtick ... what is store? wh you use two functions? recursive what? where is the weak reference?

Comment: backtick is markdown symbol. store is global state.  Two functions are for reusability and separation into smart and presentation components.

Before the update, I wired recursively which is likely what you'd go with to show an object that goes deep.

Comment: look, there are tons of examples in this page. try to find out if any of those helps. https://viperhtml.js.org/hyperhtml/examples/ I really don't know what you are trying to do. What is the goal, the use case ... the code is broken ... cannot help much.